# How can I stop webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Does anyone know how to stop webpack-dev-server? I have tried to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, it's doesn't work, no matter I press it once or twice. Additionally, even though I close the command line interface, It still works. And even if I change the server port, the previous server port still works. So I have to change the server port everytime when I close the CLI or want to change some parameters in webpack.config.js.

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
 entry: {
  main: './src/main.js'
 },
 output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: 'bundle.js',
 },
 devtool: false,
 module: {
  rules: [{
   test: /\.css$/,
   use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: "style-loader",
    use: "css-loader"
  })},{
   test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
   use: ['babel-loader'],
   exclude: /node_modules/
  }]
 },
 devServer: {
  contentBase: './dist',
  hot: true,
  port: 8088,
 },
 plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   title: "Hello React",
   template: "template.html",
  }),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new ExtractTextPlugin("style.bundle.css")
 ]
};
```

And here is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "react-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js",
    "produce": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "author": "dongxu <dongxu2048@gmail.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

Addtionally, there is my console window:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlenv.png)

As you see, I have pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> twice, subsequently, I changed the content of file, the webpack-dev-server compiles again, and I can still see the content by refresh my browser.

Comment: I've used Ctrl+C to stop it on every platform I've been on without fail. There must be something else going on

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your console when you try to use Ctrl + C?

Comment: does pressing 'q' helps?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of the process, you can use the command to kill the process.
I just use  "Ctrl + c" twice ,stop the webpack-dev-server

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.
For me Ctrl+C while compiling does work but takes many seconds to die (and keeps spewing progress %), while Ctrl+\ makes webpack-dev-server (3.10.1) shut up immediately

Ctrl+\ sends SIGQUIT to current forground job.  It's original purpose was debugging — kill a program and dump its memory to a `core` file, but the saving is disabled on many systems nowdays. It tends to be more "violent" than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> SIGINT as almost no program catches SIGQUIT.

The latest open issue seems to be 
https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1479

Caveat: as other killing solutions, it won't allow the server to cleanup, as someone mentioned on that issue:

> you kill process immediately, but in this moment somebody/something can write file to fs or do other async call and it is bad

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know how to stop webpack-dev-server?

Go to Task-Manager and close the task `Node.js: Server-side JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8088"
```

use it as inline might help.

It searches for the config file in the root directory.So --config is preferably used only when the config file is somewhere deep in the directory.

Comment: or config is useful when you have several webpack configuration depending on application environment